# Unable to See Text After Installing Ambiance-Dark Sidebar Theme

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, themes

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and have installed Ambiance Dark Sidebar Theme.

Now I can see the dark ambiance side bar, but in the main Ubuntu window of
Nautilus  I see the orange Folders (ambiance)  but the writing under the folders
is almost totally white.

How to reestablish the black writing under the folders?

Comment: I also have the same problem. Ambiance Dark Sidebar was made by [Warioring64](http://askubuntu.com/users/18612/warrioring64) for Ubuntu 11.10. I have also searched for a fix, but was unable to find. In [Web Up8](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/11/download-ambiance-with-dark-nautilus-3.html), one user also says the same thing, but the only solution is whether to wait for Ubuntu to change this behaviour or ask for help from Warioring64. Maybe he would update his theme for 12.04.

Comment: @ŞâkirAşçı - see if that nautilus.css fixes you up.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the desired effect:
[image]
[Here is a nautilus.css that did that for me.](http://pastebin.com/ntk8uWDu)

It needs to be in your `/usr/share/themes/whatever/gtk-3.0/apps/` folder, then log-out and back in to apply it.